# What kind of mathematical knot is the square knot?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

What kind of knot is the square knot? I made an attempt to calculate the Connway notation of the square knot and it did not match with any of the prime knots. Either I did the calculation wrong or the prime knot is a composition of two primes.

Depending on which ends are fused, I have the following diagrams of a square knot.

The first diagram looks more like a link of two loops than a knot, but I am not sure.

[image]

This second diagram came from me tying a square knot and fusing the open end. This is from a single string so I don't think it is possible for it to be a loop.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first diagram is actually equivalent to the *un*link of two components. Notice how you can just slip one of them out of the other.

The second diagram represents a nontrivial knot, but it is not *prime* (this requires proof, but it's true) so you won't find it in the [knot tables](http://katlas.org/wiki/The_Rolfsen_Knot_Table). A typical notation for it is $K_{3_1} \mathbin{\#} \overline{K}_{3_1}$ to indicate that it is the [connected sum](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Connected_sum#Connected_sum_of_knots) of the trefoil knot $K_{3_1}$ and its mirror image $\overline{K}_{3_1}$.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks, I was thinking it must be a connected version of a trefoil. I did not realize I could take a mirror.

Comment: Rumination, which of these diagrams would you say represents a square knot. The crossings are the same, but how one connects the end of the strings makes all the difference.

Comment: Definitely, I would call the second one a square knot since it’s actually knotted and since it only consists of one component.

Comment: By the way, some knots are [equivalent to their mirror image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_knot), but most, including the trefoil, are not. Knot tables only list one of each pair.